# highcharts export server - variable-pie with curl / POST

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to use the highcharts export server generate a variable pie chart (as well as a stacked chart - more on that later).

I am using both curl and a POST request with JSON data. Both have problems. On both the `export.highcharts.com` as well as a local, docker export server. All chart configs essentially are those as per the highcharts site.

As an aside, the "simple" example chart works well in both usage scenarios.

Now, here's the curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile": {"chart": {"type": "variablepie"}, "title": {"text": "Countriescomparedbypopulationdensityandtotalarea."}, "series": [{"minPointSize": 10, "innerSize": "20%", "zMin": 0, "name": "countries", "data": [{"name": "Spain", "y": 505, "z": 92}, {"name": "France", "y": 551, "z": 11}, {"name": "Poland", "y": 312, "z": 12}]}]}, "type": "svg", "resources": {"files": "highcharts.js,modules/exporting.js,modules/export-data.js,modules/variable-pie.js"}}' http://export.highcharts.com -o /tmp/highcharts_testchart.svg
```

The POST with a payload as per the above curl command, returns a 400; however, the server response contains the following html snippet:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token "
>       at parse (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
>       at /var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:116:18
>       at invokeCallback (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:262:16)
>       at done (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:251:7)
>       at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/app/current/node_modules/highcharts-export-server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:307:7)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)

Has anyone managed to get a pie chart to work using the export server? Anyone with comments on the stack trace?

**UPDATE**  The below has been fixed (an extra quote failed the POST request)

Lastly, on to stacked charts.  Here it gets confusing. the `curl` command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile": {"chart": {"type": "column"}, "title": {"text": "Stacked column chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas"]}, "yAxis": {"min": 0, "title": {"text": "Total fruit consumption"}, "stackLabels": {"enabled": true, "style": {"fontWeight": "bold"}}}, "legend": {"align": "right", "x": -30, "verticalAlign": "top", "y": 25, "floating": true, "borderColor": "#CCC", "borderWidth": 1, "shadow": false}, "plotOptions": {"column": {"stacking": "normal", "dataLabels": {"enabled": true}}}, "series": [{"name": "John", "data": [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]}, {"name": "Jane", "data": [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]}, {"name": "Joe", "data": [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]}]}, "type": "svg", "resources": {"files": "highcharts.js,modules/exporting.js,modules/export-data.js"}}' http://export.highcharts.com -o /tmp/highcharts_testchart.svg
```

works fine - and produces a perfectly fine image.

The , OST however - same payload - gives the above stack trace.

Thoughts? Comments?

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce it. I've got a correct image and no response from the server.

Comment: progress - in same shape! so... it seems to work for you. could you please post the curl command that worked for you? Using the xact command posted above, I am still getting: `error on line 1 at column 136: Document is empty`  I do think it is something minor, something stupid; extra character, missing comma - or some such :-(

Comment: in fact, I just tried the pdf variant - which I hadn't tried previously - and am getting: `Chart input data error
Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17` This all points to the "resources" being incorrectly specified. @WojciechChmiel could you please check/confirm with your (working) version? Thanks

Comment: last comment, I promise: browser-side, the charts work perfectly fine; we are using the JS and generate much more complex charts than in the example; all work well.  The problem described occurs only when using the export-server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. Check this thread on `node-export-server` Github: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/issues/156. As you can see there are several modules that are missing and it is required to add them manually.

1) In your `node-export-server` repository find **build.js** file and add `variable-pie` module to this object:

```
const cdnScriptsOptional = {
  '{{version}}/modules/sunburst.js': 1,
  '{{version}}/modules/xrange.js': 1,
  '{{version}}/modules/streamgraph.js': 1,
  '{{version}}/modules/tilemap.js': 1,
  '{{version}}/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js': 1,
  '{{version}}/modules/variable-pie.js': 1
};
```

2) Rebuild the server (see https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#setup-injecting-the-highcharts-dependency):

- to do this manually you can run `node build.js` (in node-export-server folder)

3) Start the server:

```
highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1
```

4) Run this curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":{"chart": {"type": "variablepie"}, "title": {"text": "Title"}, "series": [{"minPointSize": 10, "innerSize": "20%", "zMin": 0, "name": "countries", "data": [{"name": "Spain", "y": 505, "z": 92}, {"name": "France", "y": 551, "z": 11}, {"name": "Poland", "y": 312, "z": 12}]}]}, "type": "svg"}' 127.0.0.1:7801 -o chart.svg
```

Unfortunately, you can't force **http://export.highcharts.com** to add `variable-pie` module. For now, it is possible to export this series type only by using your own node-export-server.

Comment: Mate, great minds think alike! I came to exactly the same answer (albeit by stabbing in the dark long enough :-)  Quite right - I rebuilt my own server with exactly that one module added.  All I am doing now is to check that _our_ charts work correctly (rather than just the sample).  Thanks for your efforts and input. Kudos!